# Angular 2 Stop *NgFor if certain value is funded

Tags: angular

I have a JSon like this:

```
[
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country1", etc...}
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country2", etc...}
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country1", etc...}
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country1", etc...}
]
```

...and code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
  <ng-container *ngIf="contact.country == 'country1'">
  <div>COUNTRY1</div>
</ng-container></ng-container>
```

This code create the COUNTRY1 every time it find "country1"
i'd like to print the country value once. is it possible?

Comment: You can group your data first by country into another array and iterate through this array in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need first to filter your list based on your filter criteria and print filtered result:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of contacts | filterBy: 'country1'">
  <ng-container ...>
  <div>COUNTRY1</div>
</ng-container></ng-container>
```

And create pipe to filter

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBy'
})
export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[], filter: string): any[] {
    return value.filter(x => x.country === filter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a pipe that filters the array with unique items:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterUnique',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    // Remove the duplicate elements
    let uniqueArray = value.filter(function (el, index, array) { 
      return array.indexOf (el) == index;
    });

    return uniqueArray;
  }
}
```

Then you can apply your pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of contacts | filterUnique">
  <ng-container ...>
  <div>COUNTRY1</div>
</ng-container></ng-container>
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/yxvoKVD3Nvgz0T3AB7w3?p=preview

**OR**

If you don't want to use pipes then you can use a set of all the values:

```
myList = [
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country1", etc...}
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country2", etc...}
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country1", etc...}
{"Name": "xxxx", "country": "country1", etc...}
];

myNewSet =  Array.from(new Set(myList ));
```

Then use this set in the template.